# Memory Game Cards Not Rotating Properly

Tags: html, css

I have been learning how to create a memory game and thought I was following the instructions carefully but I have run into a snag.  In my html, I have a div for the card and two child divs to style the front and back of the card.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="memory_board">
        <div class="card">
            <div id="back0" class="cardFace cardFaceBack"></div>
            <div id="front0" class="cardFace cardFaceFront" class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The number of cards for the memory game will vary.

When I run the code, they are stacked on top of each other meaning when you click on one card, the back flips over as expected but the front flips over underneath its original position.  Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Life_Long_Learner2018/pen/WNZZOYZ).  How can I adjust me code so that it looks like the card flips over properly?

===============  Edit  ===================

Quick question, when I include a link to codepen, do I still have include all of the code?

The css for this game is:

```
* {

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}

div.container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

div#memory_board{

    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    perspective: 1000px;

}

.card {

    width:100px;
    height:133px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;

}

.card.is-flipped {

    transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);

}

.cardFace {

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.cardFaceFront {

    position: inherit; 
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.cardFaceBack {

    background: url("https://images.cdn2.stockunlimited.net/preview1300/playing-cards- 
    background_1608080.jpg"); no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    border:#000 1px solid;

}
```

In addition, the javascript for this program is:

```
var memory_array = ['A','A','B','B'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;

const memory_board = document.getElementById('memory_board');

let getRndInteger = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min

//  the following function randomly shuffles elements in an array using the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) shuffle

let shuffle = array => {

    let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

// While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];

    }

    return array;

}

function initiateCard () {

    let card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

    card.forEach( card => card.addEventListener ( 'click', () => {

      card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');

    }));

}

function newBoard() {

    let memoryArray = shuffle (memory_array);

    for (let i = 0; i <= memoryArray.length - 1; i++) {

        document.getElementById("front" + i).innerText = memory_array[i];

    }

}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    newBoard ();
    initiateCard ();

});
```

When the game starts, the memory_array shuffles propery and each element is distributed to the cards.  However, when you turn a card, [image: Picture of Card after turned.]

I thought I had followed the instructions but I do not understand why, when turned, the front face is below where the back was.  What adjustments do I have to make, after turning the card, so the front of the card in the same place as the back of the card, not below it.

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response and I have edited the question.  I did originally incldue the rest of the code becuase I included a link to a codepen with the program.  At the time, SO would not let me submit the question it detected a link to codepen but still required some code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

an animation or a gif will be of help to as what you want to achieve, from your comment in your code I could see you are trying to replicate this, but the way you structure your code doesn't seem to be as this

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a couple of things. I couldn't get your js to work. Getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')".

And with your CSS you need to position the front and back with `position: absolute;` otherwise, they affect each other. The back was pushing the front down the page.

And if you set `transform-origin: center center;` you don't need to do the additional `transform: translateY(-100%);`

```js
        var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'];
        var memory_values = [];
        var memory_tile_ids = [];
        var tiles_flipped = 0;

        const memory_board = document.getElementById('memory_board');

        let getRndInteger = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min

        //  the following function randomly shuffles elements in an array using the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) shuffle

        let shuffle = array => {

            let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;

            // While there remain elements to shuffle...
            while (currentIndex != 0) {

                // Pick a remaining element...
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                currentIndex--;

                // And swap it with the current element.
                [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                    array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];

            }

            return array;

        }

        function initiateCard() {

            let card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

            card.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', () => {

                card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');

            }));

        }

        function newBoard() {

            let memoryArray = shuffle(memory_array);

            for (let i = 0; i <= memoryArray.length - 1; i++) {

                document.getElementById("front" + i).innerText = memory_array[i];

            }

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            newBoard();
            initiateCard();

        });
```

```css
      * {

            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;

        }

        div.container {

            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

        }

        div#memory_board {

            background: #CCC;
            border: #999 1px solid;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            perspective: 1000px;

        }

        .card {
            width: 100px;
            height: 133px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px;
            /* padding: 10px; */
            transition: transform 1s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            transform-origin: center center;
        }

        .card.is-flipped {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .cardFace {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .cardFaceFront {
            position: absolute;
            background: whitesmoke;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 40px;
            border: #000 1px solid;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .cardFaceBack {
            background: url("https://images.cdn2.stockunlimited.net/preview1300/playing-cards-background_1608080.jpg") no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            position: absolute;
            border: #000 1px solid;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div id="memory_board">
            <div class="card is-flipped">
                <div id="back0" class="cardFace cardFaceBack"></div>
                <div id="front0" class="cardFace cardFaceFront" class="card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div id="back0" class="cardFace cardFaceBack"></div>
                <div id="front0" class="cardFace cardFaceFront" class="card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div id="back0" class="cardFace cardFaceBack"></div>
                <div id="front0" class="cardFace cardFaceFront" class="card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div id="back0" class="cardFace cardFaceBack"></div>
                <div id="front0" class="cardFace cardFaceFront" class="card"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```